# How can prevent confluence from auto-linkyfing square brackets produced by a macro?

Tags: sql, macros, escaping, sanitization, confluence

I'm using [Atlassian Confluence](http://confluence.atlassian.com/) (woe is me).

I have an `{sql}` macro inside a `groovy` macro in a wiki markup block. Now, the SQL selects some strings which look like `Foo[Bar]`. The results wiki page auto-linkifies the bar, i.e. you get

Foo[Bar](http://some.where.com/bar)

which is not what I want. I tried something like

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(name, '[', '\['), ']', '\]') FROM mytable;
```

but that triggered an error, while

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(name, '[', '\\['), ']', '\\]') FROM mytable;
```

didn't trigger an error but also did not help. What can I do?

Comment: Try `Foo![Bar]`? Some wiki syntaxes use an exclamation point for escape

Comment: @lc.: That has no effect.

Comment: I believe the problem is that your macro is outputting the string in wiki-markup. A simple solution would be to make sure that you're not outputting wiki-markup. Maybe if you enclose the output in {html} tags.

Comment: @MNRSullivan: Make that an answer so I can accept it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your macro is outputting the string in wiki-markup. A simple solution would be to make sure that you're preventing the output being interpreted as wiki-markup, by enclosing the result in `{html}` tags.